# Duplicate Entry Hierarchy

Tags: channel-entries, entries, duplicate, mx-cloner

Running EE 2.7.2

Wondering if there's an elegant way to duplicate an entry AND at the same time take the entire child tree/structure with it.

Basically, we have around 450 pages that live under the English side of the site, we'll call it 'EN' and need to duplicate this, exactly, on the French side.

Something like https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner is what I'm looking for but that only does one entry at a time. I'd like to clone the top level and copy that and the 5 levels below is in one fell swoop.

Is that a thing?

Comment: I am afraid there is no plugin for the functionality you are looking for. Perhaps you can modify mx-cloner to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this with a custom script. Query for all of the entries you want to duplicate using whatever criteria works best, then one-by-one take their existing data and create new entries via the [Channel Entries API](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/api/api_channel_entries.html). Include any hierarchical Pages data with each entry (`pages_uri`) (possibly as simple as doing a str_replace for `/en/` to `/fr/` for example).

Will take some trial and error though!